# Adding flags to rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

The syntax I need to use with whatever version of PHP/Apache/whatever is installed on the server to allow .htaccess rewrite rules to work looks like this:

```
Redirect 301 "/birthcare" /hospital-services/women-childrens-health/childbirth-center/
```

How can I add flags such as [L] Last and [NC] Case insensitive to that syntax.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `RewriteRule` instead of `Redirect` directive.

Comment: flags are part of mod-rewrite. you can not use them with Redirect (mod-alias)